# What is the difference between AbortRequest and Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ip-restrictions

According to [Dynamic IP Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/) document in Microsoft :

> AbortRequest :    Specifies that by default IIS should send a deny mode
>   response of Abort back to clients. The numeric value is 0.
>
> Forbidden : Specifies that by default IIS should send a deny mode
>   response of Forbidden back to clients. The numeric value is 403.

The description seems similar. Is it just about numeric value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As that article says, aborting simply drops the connection without bothering to complete the request or give any reason for the cancellation.

Sending a Forbidden response means it will complete the request and send a HTTP status code, but it denies the user access to the originally requested resource. Some relevant response data may still be returned to the caller (even if it's just a string saying "Forbidden").